# MSTest in VS2008 keeps looking in the wrong directory for deployment items

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest

I have the localtestrun.testrunconfig file with some files and folders, and they *are* being copied out to the test run results Out directory, but when the tests are run, it can't find the items, because it's looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE instead of the proper test results directory.

Any ideas on why VS2008 is suddenly looking in the wrong place, for tests that have been run many, many times before without issue?